# What kind of physics research can a high-schooler get involved in and form new discoveries in?

Tags: soft-question

I am a high school student with a strong background in physics, engineering, and computer science. I am very interested in research and formulating my own discoveries in order to learn more about combining these topics and how I can some day combine my passions into a longer term research project. Ideally, I would like to combine my interests by creating a computer simulation of a problem and then building a setup to gather actual results and analyze them. About what kinds of topics would I be able to form new and non-trivial discoveries through this method?

Comment: Hi okarin, this is not the type of question that is well suited to our QA format.  You're basically asking for a list of opinions from folks.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I thought that that was the purpose of a soft question? Could you recommend a different place where I could get advice on this question? Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Almost every soft-question is actually off topic here.  We really should do away with the tag altogether but I don't think there is a consensus for doing so.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Would it be best for me to delete the post?

Comment: no, I don't think so.  You might get somebody to post a few good links here in the comments.  Also there is a chance nobody else agrees with me and won't vote to close the question.

Comment: Usually the hardest thing to learn in research is what questions are worth pursuing - what does the community care about? what is doable? what has already been done? Most researchers learn by some form of apprenticeship - work in a lab, have an adviser, hang out with Doc Brown after school, etc. Asking around at a nearby university can prove fruitful for finding a mentor, but you have to be extra careful you are *taught* and not just used for cheap labor.